# Failure to create availability group

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I"m having a problem creating a new Availability group in a windows cluster. I have 3 nodes in the cluster. Two nodes are running as a FCI and a single stand-alone node that's a member of the windows cluster.

> Msg 19405, Level 16, State 17, Line 2 Failed to create, join or add
>   replica to availability group 'SQL Cluster 2', because node 'DRNode'
>   is a possible owner for both replica 'DRNode' and 'SQL Instance'. If
>   one replica is failover cluster instance, remove the overlapped node
>   from its possible owners and try again.

I've fixed this issue by **removing the DRNode from being a possible owner of the SQL FCI**, but the issue persists.

Do I need to restart the role to make it effective?

I've confirmed in PS that it's correct.

```
 PS C:\Windows\system32> get-clusterownernode -resource "SQL Network
 Name (FCI Name)"

ClusterObject                                               OwnerNodes
-------------                                               ---------- 
SQL Network Name (FCI Name)                                 {Node1, Node2}
```

Comment: check this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4967/fixing-error-19405-when-configuring-sql-server-availability-groups/

Comment: The PS output shows the network name is not able to be owned by Node3, but what about the SQL Server instance resource itself?

Comment: It's the same as the network name. The weird thing is that I have an identical cluster that's working fine, so I have something to compare it to. And that SQL instance is able to be owned by all 3 nodes. But on the problem cluster, the 3rd node is not a possible owner, and even if I select it, click ok, then reopen it, it's unselected again.

Comment: CR241 - Yes I've seen that, I have all the symptoms, but I've implemented the solution they gave but the issue persists. I"ve even evicted the 3rd node then re-added it so try to clear out any weird lingering issue but the problem persists.

Comment: Can you provide a list of all ClusterObjects and their respective OwnerNodes?